# Can't parse body of page

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying parse some `href` from one page, my code looks like:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string htmlCode = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.firmy.cz/Auto-moto");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'companyWrap')]");
string target = "";
foreach (HtmlNode link in collection)
{
    target = target +"\n"+ link.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

On this page my `doc.ParsedText` haven't body `<body id="root" class="root">
</body>` but if i go to page i see elements of body. Can u tell me where is a problem?

> Blockquote

Comment: It looks like the website is a Single Page Application. Load it with JavaScript disabled and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source of the URL you are trying to parse (https://www.firmy.cz/Auto-moto), you can see that the body is empty.

It seems like the page is loading the content through JavaScript on the client side and will thus not be available for you to parse.

Comment: Thank you for informations. I will try find another way to get data from this page.